# <noscript> HTML after axios.get request

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to get the data of this website, is there something wrong with my code or is this an issue on the requested website side?

```js
data() {
  return {
    proxy: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
    website: 'https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=MC_MX&query_string=205214',
  }
},
mounted: function () {
  axios.get(this.proxy + this.website)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    })
}
```

Instead of getting the data I get this:

[image]

Comment: Fetching a website just returns the source code. If the website uses JavaScript to update its contents dynamically, you won't get that with Axios.

Comment: is there a workaround to get the data?

Comment: Use other tools like Selenium WebDriver to emulate a browser.

Comment: I don't see a problem in you code it seems like the service response in the one with the issue

Comment: The data is in the markup that has been fetched. You just need to extract it.

Comment: @marzelin how should I extract it??

Comment: use regex on raw string or put the body into an iframe and query elements.